# Apply a function to every item of an arbitrarily nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list `a = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5]` and I want to apply a function that will raise every number to the power of 2. The result will be like this:

```
a = [1, 4, [9, 16], 25]
```

I tried `a = [list(map(lambda x : x * x, x)) for x in a]` but it gives this error

```
'int' object is not iterable
```

How we can fix this issue? How can I apply a function over a nested list?

Comment: You are trying to `apply` your function to each outer list item, but some of them are lists (ok to apply) and the others are numbers (not ok to apply).

Comment: You can flatten your irregular list and then apply lambda. Below is the duplicate link on how to flatten

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need a recursive function that distinguishes between lists and scalars:

```
def square(item):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return [square(x) for x in item]
    else:
        return item * item

square(a)
#[1, 4, [9, 16], 25]
```

Incidentally, this approach works for arbitrary-nested lists.

Here's a more general solution:

```
def apply(item, fun):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return [apply(x, fun) for x in item]
    else:
        return fun(item)

apply(a, lambda x: x * x)
#[1, 4, [9, 16], 25]
```

Comment: completely unrelated, but your `apply` looks like a ["functor"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor), interesting how/where these things turn up!

Answer (score 3):

You are decomposing your list into its elements -some of them are lists which can not be multiplied with itself (`[3,4]*[3,4]`).

Not sure if that is smart - but you can use a "recursing" lambda:

```
a =[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]

l = lambda x : x * x if isinstance(x,int) else list(map(l,x))
a = list(map(l, a))

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, [9, 16], 25]
```

---

Works also for "deeper" levels:

```
a =[1, 2, [3, [7,8], 4], 5]
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, [9, [49, 64], 16], 25]
```

but will crash if you mix non-iterables things into the mix